# Attach to click event outside page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following button in my ASPX page -

```
 $('#btnHello').click(function () {
   alert('Hi there');
 });
```

Which works as expected and presents the alert, however I want to move this event into my **global.js** file with the exact same logic. I am referencing this file at the top of my ASPX page however the event is not firing. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're executing is a function, at the very beginning:

```
 $('#btnHello').click(function () {
    alert('Hi there');
 });
```

You're hooking up your alert function to the element `#btnHello`.

But at the time it executes, `#btnHello` hasn't been loaded.  It doesn't exist yet.  So nothing gets hooked up.

You can get around this either by executing your code at the very end, or (more reliably, I think) deferring this code's execution until the document has finished loading:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnHello').click(function () {
       alert('Hi there');
     });
 });
```

You would put this in your global.js, but it wouldn't execute until your page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation:

```
$(<parent_of_btnHello>).on("click", "#btnHello", function () {
    alert('Hi there');
});
```

..where `<parent_of_btnHello>` should be an element that is loaded when the handler is added. For example:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnHello", function () {
    alert('Hi there');
});
```

It also can be `$(document)` or `$("html")` or any container of your button, that is loaded the the code from `global.js` file is executed.

You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22041545/1420197) too.

---

Another way is to put your initial code inside of `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#btnHello').click(function () {
      alert('Hi there');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is no such element when you are trying to bind an event.

Try to wrap your code with document.ready

```
$(function() {
   $('#btnHello').click(function () {
      alert('Hi there');
   });
})
```