# Load jQuery after HTML change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these HTML codes in 'body' tag:

```
<body>
    <center>
        Hello!<br />
        <textarea cols="65" rows="10" id="code"></textarea>
    </center>
</body>
```

And I want to place all of my page codes in above textarea with this codes in jQuery:

```
$("textarea#code").val( $('body').html() );
```

OK, now I want to let user change the HTML of 'body' in that 'textarea' using this:

```
$("textarea#code").change(function(){
    $('body').html( $(this).val() );

    $("textarea#code").val( $('body').html() );
});
```

After first change all things are OK and HTML changes successfully, but after doing that, the user can not change HTML for the second time! In other words, JavaScript didn't load.

Here's my snippet:

```js
$("textarea#code").val( $('body').html() );

$("textarea#code").change(function(){
    $('body').html( $(this).val() );
    
    $("textarea#code").val( $('body').html() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <center>
        Hello!<br />
        <textarea cols="65" rows="10" id="code"></textarea>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not that JavaScript didn't load, it's that you ran into an infinite loop. You update the value of the `textarea` inside the `change` event, which re-fires the `change` event, and it repeats.

Comment: Do you consider accepting an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You need delegation:

```
$("textarea#code").val($('body').html());
$(document).change("textarea#code", function (e) {
    $('body').html($(e.target).val());
    $("textarea#code").val($('body').html());
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v1L9nfb0/2/)

- [What delegation means?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22041545/1420197)

Answer (score 1):

`html` method as setter is *destructive*, i.e. it replaces all the contents by parsing the passed value and generating *new* elements. Event handlers are bound to elements and each DOM object is unique. After using `html` method the old elements will be removed, so the event handlers attached to them won't function anymore. You should use event delegation in this case.

That being said using a `textatea` here for modifying HTML content of the entire page doesn't make a lot of sense. If you want to edit the page dynamically you can use a WYSIWYG editor or `contentEditable` attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

HTML in your body is dynamically changing. You have to use,

```
$(document).on('change','textarea#code',function(){
    $('body').html( $(this).val() );
    $("textarea#code").val( $('body').html() );
});
```

instead

```
$("textarea#code").change(function(){
    $('body').html( $(this).val() );

    $("textarea#code").val( $('body').html() );
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v1L9nfb0/3/)