# Jquery update dom after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Class jquery hover function are  working after scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').hover(function(){
        alert('hello');
    },function(){
        alert('hello not');
    });
});
```

on hovering images loaded on first site are showing alert hello but after scroll images load(lazzy loading). On hovering those images alert is not showing.

Comment: use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/event-delegation) for dynamic element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work after loading new images

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("body").on("mouseenter", "img", function(){
        alert('hello');
    });

    $("body").on("mouseleave", "img", function(){
        alert('hello not');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need delegation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).hover('img', function(){
        alert('hello');
    },function(){
        alert('hello not');
    });
});
```

- [See this answer for more information about **Direct and delegated events**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22041545/1420197)