# How to add click event to dynamic list view in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have to add click event to the dynamic list view. When I click this list it redirect to more detail page. I am fetching the list of Hotels available in particular area and insert into list-view. Now when I click any particular list Hotels redirect to more detail page.
check the following image list view of list of hotels available. Every hotel have unique id So when I click any list it will use that unique hotel id and fetch more details information of that hotel from server and show on one dedicated page for that particular Hotel. **My Question is How I add click even on dynamic list view and pass that unique Hotel Id so that later I am able to fetch more information from server using that Hotel Id.**

[image]

My script code, How to add click even in dynamic list

```
<script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                $("#btnReg").click(function(){ 
                    $("#listHotelsOptions").empty();
                    var distance = document.getElementById('distance_id').value; 
                    var output=""; 
                    var hiddenId="";
                    $.ajax({ 
                            url:"http://192.168.1.4/Experiements/webservices/getHotels.php", 
                            type:"GET", 
                            dataType:"json", 
                            data:{type:"login", Distance:distance}, 
                            ContentType:"application/json", 
                            success: function(response){ 
                            console.log(response) 
                                $.each(response, function(index,value){                                                                 
                                          hiddenId+='<li  type="hidden">'+value.Hotel.Id+'</li>';
                                          output+='<li ><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"> <img alt="chef" src="./images/chef.min.png" width="20px" height="20px" >'+value.Hotel.Name+' has'+value.Hotel.Romms+'</a></li>';
                                }); 
        $("#listHotelsOption").append(output).listview().listview('refresh'); 
                        }, 
                            error: function(err){ 
                            alert(JSON.stringify(err)); 
                        } 
                    }) //ajax 
                }); //click 
            }); //ready 
</script>
```

Comment: You need delegation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22041545/1420197

Comment: @ Ionică Bizău, thanks for yr reply, but I am new in web technology, I need more specific..

Comment: See the very basic sample, that too in plain javascript on event delegation. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 2 LI elements, save the hotel id as a **[data-attribute](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jqmData/)** of the visible LI:

```
$.each(response, function(index,value){                                                                 
    output+='<li data-hotelid="'+value.Hotel.Id+'"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"> <img alt="chef" src="./images/chef.min.png" width="20px" height="20px" >'+value.Hotel.Name+' has'+value.Hotel.Romms+'</a></li>';
});
```

Instead of `$(document).ready(function(){` in jQuery Mobile you should use one of the page events e.g. pagecreate. On page creation create a click handler for all LIs using **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** so that dynamically created ones are included. Use the jQM method **[jqmData()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jqmData/)** to retrieve the id data-attribute from the LI:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#yourpageid", function(){
    $("#listHotelsOption").on("click", "li", function(){
        //get hotel id
        var id = $(this).jqmData("hotelid");
        ... rest of click handler
    });

    $("#btnReg").on("click", function(){
       //your code to dynamically create list
    });  
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lb2m318p/)**

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have some confusion about your code, My requirement is when I click #btnReg, It will give all hotel  available within the that area. #listHotelOption is unsorted list which contains all hotels after pressing #btnReg. Now which I click on any particular list as above It will redirect to the #hotelPage, which have more details. Now these details will be fill by fetching information from the database based on hotel_id. Hotel_id comes first time when pressing the #btnReg for every hotels. Thanks, I am waiting for reply...

Comment: @neelabhsingh, that is exactly what my code does. Keep btnReg click as you had it but use the data-attribute for the hotel id (my first code sample), then add the click event for the LIs which gets the hotel id. You will need to provide the rest of the code that retrieves hotel details.

Comment: @neelabhsingh, I have added a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lb2m318p/

Comment: @neelabhsingh, did you change "#yourpageid" to the actual page id of your data-role="page" DIV?

Comment: thanks for such vivid explanation, I copied the our code and paste on eclipse it is not working..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#btnReg").on('click',function(){ 

}); //click
```

EDIT:

```
$.each(response, function(index,value){                                                                 
  hiddenId+='<li  type="hidden">'+value.Hotel.Id+'</li>';
  output+='<li class="hotel"  ><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"> <img alt="chef" src="./images/chef.min.png" width="20px" height="20px" >'+value.Hotel.Name+' has'+value.Hotel.Romms+'</a></li>';
}); 

$(".hotel").on('click',function(){ 

}); //click
```

EDIT2

```
$(".hotel").live('click',function(){ 

}); //click 

$(".hotel").delegate('click',function(){ 

}); //click
```

EDIT3

```
'<li class="hotel" id="'+value.Hotel.Id+'"  ><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"> <img alt="chef" src="./images/chef.min.png" width="20px" height="20px" >'+value.Hotel.Name+' has'+value.Hotel.Romms+'</a></li>';

$(".hotel").live('click',function(){ 
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
}); //click
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, I don't need click on #btnReg, but on  $.each(response, function(index,value){                                                                 
                                          hiddenId+='<li  type="hidden">'+value.Hotel.Id+'</li>';
                                          output+='<li ><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"> <img alt="chef" src="./images/chef.min.png" width="20px" height="20px" >'+value.Hotel.Name+' has'+value.Hotel.Romms+'</a></li>';
                                });

Comment: $(".hotel").on('click',function(){          alert("1");        }); not working.. alert is nor showing..

Comment: now It is working, thanks, But my need is that when I click any list it get unique Id and using that Id I have to fetch the data and put that information into separate page Which has like  name of Hotel ,price , image of rooms, and all other information, That page design will be same for every hotel and  It will have id for every element like for price, image of room so I have to just assign new fetch value..

Comment: but is was not working. and var id = $(this).attr('id'); var id = $(this).attr('Id'); I try both..., please check edit 3 and make id to Id..

Comment: I am tring the following..$(".hotel").live('click',function(){        var id=$(this).attr('value.Chef.Id');
alert(id);        });

Answer (score 0):

put

```
 <a href="detail.html?id=' + value.Hotel.Id + '"> before your <li>
```

use this function to get id in detail page

```
    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars; // this is your id value
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate this  <a href="detail.html?id=' + value.Hotel.Id + '">  what we are doing. How I will get the hotel id from detail page.

Comment: put your <li> within <a> so that whenever it will work as link, and   pass your hotel id with this using?id=Hotelid and get that id in detail page.