# How to add click event to dynamic list view in JQuery in phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, cordova

I have to add click event to the dynamic list view. When I click this list it redirect to more detail page. I am fetching the list of Hotels available in particular area and insert into list-view. Now when I click any particular list Hotels redirect to more detail page.
check the following image list view of list of hotels available. Every hotel have unique id So when I click any list it will use that unique hotel id and fetch more details information of that hotel from server and show on one dedicated page for that particular Hotel. My Question is How I add click even on dynamic list view and **pass that unique Hotel Id** so that later I am able to fetch more information from server using that Hotel Id.

[image]

**My script code, How to add click even in dynamic list**

```
    <script> 
                $(document).ready(function(){ 
                    $("#btnReg").click(function(){ 
                        $("#listHotelsOptions").empty();
                        var distance = document.getElementById('distance_id').value; 
                        var output=""; 
                        var hiddenId="";
                        $.ajax({ 
                                url:"http://192.168.1.4/Experiements/webservices/getHotels.php", 
                                type:"GET", 
                                dataType:"json", 
                                data:{type:"login", Distance:distance}, 
                                ContentType:"application/json", 
                                success: function(response){ 
                                console.log(response) 
                                    $.each(response, function(index,value){     
            output+='<li class="hotelDetails"><a href="#hotelPage" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <img alt="chef" src="./images/chef.min.png" width="20px" height="20px" >'+value.Hotel.Name+'   
  has'+value.Hotel.Rooms+'</a></li>';
                            }); 
                            $(".hotelDetails").live('click',function(){


                            });
            $("#listHotelsOption").append(output).listview().listview('refresh'); 
                            }, 
                                error: function(err){ 
                                alert(JSON.stringify(err)); 
                            } 
                        }) //ajax 
                    }); //click 
                }); //ready 
    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add click event to dynamic list view in PhoneGap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833594/how-to-add-click-event-to-dynamic-list-view-in-phonegap)

Comment: stop opening new threads with the same question again and again

Answer (score 0):

you can put class like .listClass in every item of list and add javascript function like

```
$(".listClass").click(function(){
 called on each item click
})
```

and its working fine here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rLLdv4wu/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I write the code according to you but It is not working                                    $.each(response, function(index,value){       output+='<li class="HotelDetails"><a href="#HotelPage" style="text-decoration:none;">'+value.Hotel.Name+' has '+value.Hotel.Name+'</a></li>';
        });         $(".HotelDetails").click(function()){         alert("1");}

Comment: I am not sure about phonegap but It must work on javascript.

Then try to put it in <a>'s class or create function and assign to <a>'s onClick="function()" it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code

```
$(".hotelDetails").on('click',function(){

});
```

out side of

```
$("#btnReg").click(function(){

});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Ved, thanks for reply but is not working and I am using jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: @Ved thanks for reply but is not working and I am using jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: dont use live use on .