# jquery .change() Only Works WITHIN a Function?

Tags: jquery

I have a function I want to call when dynamically created content comes from ajax.  This bit is working fine.  I also want to call the function when the class `.check_if_checked` changes (checkbox checked or radio changed, etc.).  I have...

```
$('.check_if_checked').on('change', '#page-wrapper', function() {
    activate_step_2_button();
});

function activate_step_2_button(){
    //do stuff
}
```

The `.on` will just NOT detect changes.  If I put

```
$('.check_if_checked').on('change', '#page-wrapper', function() {
    
});
```

inside

```
function activate_step_2_button(){
    //do stuff
}
```

then it detects ok...... but then I can't directly call the function from other places (there's not a change in that case).

Oh, and if I enter

```
$('.check_if_checked').on('change', '#page-wrapper', function() {
    activate_step_2_button();
});
```

into the console everything works.

And yes, I read over [JQuery function only works within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041463/jquery-function-only-works-within-a-function) already.  This feels like a duplicate of that, but the solution there (and other similar solutions) are just not working.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I suspect it is due to the DOM elements changing after the AJAX response is received. The solution in this case would be event delegation, which the link you shared discusses.

Comment: @76484: Would that also account for the fact that it works when I enter the code into the console?  Also, aren't I already delegating via the `'#page-wrapper'` in `$('.check_if_checked').on('change', '#page-wrapper', function()`?

Comment: Possibly. It depends on the timing of when you add the listener and when the DOM is changed. Yes, you are using delegation, having `.check_if_checked` capture changes to a child `#page-wrapper`. But this looks backwards. I would assume that `#page-wrapper` wraps the page. In which case, it should be `$('#page-wrapper').on('change', '.check_if_checked', function () {})`.

Comment: ^this!!  I didn't know there was a parent/child relationship!  I can accept your answer as "the one" if you want to submit an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Simple, you misunderstood how to use Event delegation using the .on() method. Here's how: `$("#staticParent").on("eventName", ".dynamicChild", fn)` - whereas you inverted the static and dynamic selectors in your code.

Comment: @gtilflm : I don't think there is anything in what I could post that would add to the Event Delegation post you liked to. But please be sure to up vote that one!